# SQL Server 2014 - Incorrect syntax near OFFSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, offset

I'm using SQL Server 2014 management studio and I wanted to create a stored procedure but I have a problem at the very end of the code where the error "Incorrect syntax near OFFSET" appears.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGamesPlayed]
    @gameSession int,
    @datestart datetime,
    @dateend datetime,
    @orderBy nvarchar(50) = 'email',
    @sortOrder nvarchar(4) = 'asc',
    @search nvarchar(50) = '',
    @startRow int = 0,
    @rows int = 2147483647
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT t.*,
            COUNT(*) OVER() AS filteredRows,
            (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM gameplayed WHERE gameplayed.id_GameSession = @gameSession) AS totalRows
    FROM (SELECT
            DISTINCT GamesTable.[Game ID],
            GamesTable.[Rep Id],
            GamesTable.[User Id],
            GamesTable.[Date],
            GamesTable.[Email],
            GamesTable.[Name],
            GamesTable.[Phone Number],
            GamesTable.[Tokens Played],
            CASE 
                WHEN prizewon.pending = 1 THEN 'Pending'
                WHEN prizewon.skillTestingQCorrect = 1 AND prizewon.rulesAccepted = 1 THEN 'Yes'
                ELSE 'No'
            END AS [Won]

            FROM PrizeWon 
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
                    SELECT 
                        GamePlayed.id AS [Game ID],
                        GamePlayed.playedOn AS [Date],
                        users.repId AS [Rep Id],
                        users.id AS [User Id],
                        users.fullName AS [Name],
                        users.email AS [Email],
                        users.phoneNumber AS [Phone Number],
                        GamePlayed.tokensPlayed AS [Tokens Played]

                    FROM GamePlayed 
                            INNER JOIN Users on GamePlayed.id_Users = Users.id 

                    WHERE GamePlayed.id_GameSession = @gameSession) AS GamesTable ON GamesTable.[Game ID] = prizewon.id_GamePlayed

    WHERE   GamesTable.Date >= @datestart
            AND GamesTable.Date <= @dateend
            AND (   GamesTable.[Email] LIKE '%' + @search + '%' 
                OR  GamesTable.[Rep Id] LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
                OR  GamesTable.[Name] LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
                OR  GamesTable.[Game ID] LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
                )
        ) t


--order by cases must be split into datatypes       
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'asc' THEN
        CASE @orderBy -- nvarchar
            WHEN 'repid' THEN t.[Rep Id]
            WHEN 'name' THEN t.[Name]
            WHEN 'email' THEN t.[Email]
            WHEN 'phone' THEN t.[Phone Number]
            WHEN 'won' THEN t.Won
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'asc' THEN
        CASE @orderBy --date
            WHEN 'date' THEN t.Date
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'asc' THEN
        CASE @orderBy --int
            WHEN 'id' THEN t.[Game ID]
            WHEN 'tokens' THEN t.[Tokens Played]
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'desc' THEN
        CASE @orderBy -- nvarchar
            WHEN 'repid' THEN t.[Rep Id]
            WHEN 'name' THEN t.[Name]
            WHEN 'email' THEN t.[Email]
            WHEN 'phone' THEN t.[Phone Number]
            WHEN 'won' THEN t.Won
        END
    END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'desc' THEN
        CASE @orderBy --date
            WHEN 'date' THEN t.Date
        END
    END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'desc' THEN
        CASE @orderBy --int
            WHEN 'id' THEN t.[Game ID]
            WHEN 'tokens' THEN t.[Tokens Played]
        END
    END DESC 

    OFFSET @startRow ROWS FETCH NEXT @rows ROWS ONLY
END
```

I have seen in other posts that the error may appear because the OFFSET is not after an ORDER BY, but in this case it is after one ORDER BY.

Another thing that I saw is that SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `OFFSET`, but I'm using 2014.

I have also checked that the variables that I'm using are declared and they all are...

Its pretty much the only error that is keeping me from creating the procedure. If anyone could help I'll be very greatful!

Comment: You say you are using SQL Management studio 2014, but is you database also 2014? or are you by any chance running 2008R2 as a database?

Comment: Oh yeah. I just used @@version and it says Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

Answer (score 1):

After a little research I used "SELECT @@version" and found out that my database version was 2008, which doesn't support OFFSET.

A quick update to version 2012 solved the issue.